# In a pandas dataframe, I'd like to separate each month in a time series into separate dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame of several years of hourly data:

```
Timestamp                      Spd              Pres                              
2013-06-13 00:00:00            9.630            650.4
2013-06-13 01:00:00            9.309            650.4
2013-06-13 02:00:00            8.421            650.4
```

I'd like to split this data into months then find the average of each month to make an average representative year. My timestamps are my index.

Is there a good way to do this without iterating the number of hours each month into its own DataFrame with a loop?

**Solution**

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df['Month'] = df.index
df['Year'] = df.index
df['Month'] = df['Month'].apply(lambda x: x.month)
df['Year'] = df['Year'].apply(lambda x: x.year)

print(df.groupby(['Month', 'Year']).mean()
```

Comment: datetime objects have an attribute `month`, you could try mapping to it.

Comment: Do you need to separate months of different years, or do you want the separation just based on the month of the year?

Comment: I'm looking for separation for months of different years as well yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = {'Timestamp': [datetime(2013, 6, 13, 0, 0, 0), datetime(2013, 6, 13, 1, 0, 0), datetime(2013, 6, 13, 2, 0, 0)], 'Spd': [9.630 , 9.309,8.421], 'Pres': [650.4, 650.4, 650.4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('Timestamp')
df['Month'] = df.index
df['Month'] = df['Month'].apply(lambda x: x.month)

print(df.groupby('Month').mean())
```

Comment: This almost does it but i'd like the means for month of each year separated as well. Although, this is the solution to my next problem, so thanks for that! I tried repeating this step again for a year column just not sure how to groupby two conditions

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

from datetime import datetime

data = {'Timestamp': [datetime(2013, 6, 13, 0, 0, 0), datetime(2013, 6, 13, 1, 0, 0), datetime(2013, 6, 13, 2, 0, 0)], 'Spd': [9.630 , 9.309,8.421], 'Pres': [650.4, 650.4, 650.4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('Timestamp')
df['Month'] = df.index
df['Year'] = df.index

df['Month'] = df['Month'].apply(lambda x: x.month)
df['Year'] = df['Year'].apply(lambda x: x.year)

print(df.groupby(['Year', 'Month']).mean())
```

should work.
I would recommend googling 'pandas dataframe.groupby' term and have a read of the documentation. The groupby method is really useful and worth knowing everything it can do.